# Why do PHP scripts sometimes restart at the beginning of index.php while debugging?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

While debugging PHP with xdebug, sometimes a script will suddenly restart at the beginning of index.php. Why is this?

Edit:
I also sporadically get errors. For example:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getEvents() on a non-object in ...

But I never get these errors when I'm not debugging.

Comment: This would depend entirely on your code/IDE, one reason I can think of off hand:

You call script A, script A makes a curl call to script B and passes along the debug header or cookie, Another reason could be that the php page you're loading has ajax calls that are fired on load that are passing the debug header or cookie. if you have more than one simultaneous connection enabled in phpstorm for example, these calls will open a new debugger tab and jump to it making it look like the debug session started over but really its a new tab/request

Comment: Which IDE are you using

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0). It isn't curl. It seems like it is going back to index.php at random places and it doesn't happen every time. I make the request from the browser and then step through the code and this happens before anything is sent back. I'm pretty sure it isn't ajax, I will double check. It would be strange for ajax to make another request 10-15 minutes later wouldn't it?